# Using SSH to dial into a git repo

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am using an SSH Client to Dial into my Git Repo on my server.

I have the repo set up at

```
C:\Users\jameo\circletest.git
```

and I'm trying to set the ssh remote to it like this

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://jameo@10.10.10.10/C:/Users/jameo/circletest.git
```

And then do

```
git push origin master
```

But it keeps striping the "/"'s from my path, I end up with something like this:

```
fatal: /C:Usersjameocircletest.git does not appear to be a git repository
```

Even if I reverse the slash (\ or /) either way its not finding the directory.
How would I go about finding this directory on the server?

Comment: Have you tried using a regular SSH client to verify that your ssh URL/path is correct?

Comment: What is your sshd running under? Is it cygwin? If so, have you tried /cygdrive/c/Users/jameo/circletest.git as the path?

Comment: I think Im using copSSH.  And I've tried CDing to that drive under normal ssh, and it works

Comment: the problem is probably the colon in your "C:" bit. Try finding a way around that; afaik, git uses libcurl to parse urls, and a windows-style color like that isnt valid in a URL, so it'll easily get confused.

Comment: So if I don't explicitly type C:, I must just type /Users or something? I've tested it and with scp, and if I move a file to just ": ", the root directory is the C drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided it was much easier to just use SMB to dial into the directory, and then just point my repo at that mounted directory.  Not really a solution to my exact question, but I would say this:

smb is 100x easier, and there 0 software to install.

Hope this can help someone struggling with the same thing